# Browsers are requesting crossdomain.xml & /-7890*sfxd*0*sfxd*0 on my site

Tags: security, web, cross-domain

Just recently I have seen multiple sessions on my site that are repeatedly requesting /crossdomain.xml & /-7890*sfxd*0*sfxd*0.  We have had feedback from some of the folks behind these sessions that they cannot browse the site correctly.  Is anyone aware of what might be causing these requests?  We were thinking either virus or some toolbar.

The only common item we have seen on the requests is that they all are some version of IE (7, 8 or 9).

Comment: I'm seeing this too.  The only thing I can add is that the referrer for these requests is superfish.com, which looks like a browser toolbar "Superfish windowshopper"

Comment: I can confirm the same with ours.  I've sent a request to Superfish to see if they can indicate what they are looking for with that url.  Our started on 11/27/12 and we get several thousand hits a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Independently* of the nature of your site/application, ...

... the request of the `/crossdomain.xml` policy file is indicative of a [typically Adbobe Flash, Silverlight, JavaFX or the like] application running on the client workstation and attempting to assert whether your site allows the application to access your site ***on behalf of*** the user on said workstation. This assertion of the crossdomain policy is a security feature of the underlying "sandboxed" environment (Flash Player, Silverlight, etc.) aimed at protecting the user of the workstation.  That is because when accessing third party sites "on behalf" of the user, the application gains access to whatever information these sites will provide *in the context of* the various sessions or cookies the user may have readily started/obtained.

... the request of `/-7890*sfxd*0*sfxd*0` is a hint that the client (be it the application  mentioned above, some unrelated http reference, web browser plug-in or yet some other logic) is thinking that your site is either superfish.com, some online store affiliated with superfish.com or one of the many sites that send traffic to superfish.com for the purpose of sharing revenue.

Now... these two kinds of request received by your site **may well be unrelated**, even though they originate from the same workstation in some apparent simultaneity.  For example it could just be that the crossdomain policy assertion is from a web application which legitimately wishes to access some service from your site, while the "sfxd" request comes from some a plug-in on workstation's web browser (e.g. WindowsShopper or, alas, a slew of other plug-ins) which somehow trigger their requests based on whatever images the browser receives.

The fact that some of the clients which make these requests are `not able to browse your site correctly` (whatever that means...) could further indicate that some -I suspect- JavaScript logic on these clients get the root URL of their underlying application/affiliates confused with that of your site.  But that's just a guess, there's not enough context about your site to get more precise hints.

**A few suggestions to move forward**:

- Decide whether your site can and should allow crossdomain access and to whom, and remove or edit your site's crossdomain.xml file accordingly.  Too many sites seem to just put
   `<allow-access-from domain="*"/>` in their crossdomain policy file for no good reason (and hence putting their users at risk).   This first suggestion will not lead to solving the problem at hand, but I couldn't resist the cautionary warning.
- ask one of these users which "cannot access your site properly" to disable some of the plug-in (aka add-ons) on their web browser and/or to use alternate web browser, and see if that improves the situation.  Disabling plug-ins on web browser is usually very easy.  To speed up the discovery, you may suggest some kind of a dichotomy approach, disabling several plug-ins at once and continuing the experiment with half of these plug-ins or with the ones that were still enabled, depending on results with your site's proper access.
- If your application provides ads from third party sites, temporally disable these ads and see if that helps these users who "cannot access your site properly".

Comment: Thank you for the very nice answer on this.  Sorry I was vague, but we have only had Opinionlab comments to rely on so far.  Our customer support team hasn't been able to get a reply from customers regarding this yet.